# Google sheet script replace True value with checkbox only if value is true on 4 different column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi what I'm trying to do is to have the script replace  the value 'True' only to a checkmark the script I'm using now does insert checkmark but it insert it on all the selected range leaving a empty checkmark box where there is no label next to it I would like to have no checkbox if the cell on the right of the checkbox is blank I would need something like this.

[image]

Here's the code I use now

```
function addCheckbox() {

  var ws =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = ws.getSheetByName('sheet1')
  var rowCount =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('B1').getValue();
  var value = rowCount+3
 
    ss.getRange('B4:B'+value).insertCheckboxes()
  
    ss.getRange('D4:D'+value).insertCheckboxes()
  
    ss.getRange('F4:F'+value).insertCheckboxes()
  
    ss.getRange('H4:H'+value).insertCheckboxes()
 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to replace `TRUE` to the checkbox of a sheet of "sheet1".

#### Modification points:

- `insertCheckboxes()` is put the checkbox. In this case, when the cell value is not `TRUE`, the unchecked checkbox is put.
- In order to put the checkbox to only the cell value of `TRUE`, it is required to check the cell values.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function addCheckbox() {
  var ws =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = ws.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  
  // I modified below script.
  var ranges = ss.getDataRange().getValues().reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (c === true) {
        ar.push(ss.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).getA1Notation());
      }
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
  ss.getRangeList(ranges).insertCheckboxes();
}
```

- In this modification, the checkbox is put using RangeList created by checking the cell value.
- This modified script replaces the cell value of `TRUE` to the checked checkbox in "sheet1".

#### Reference:

- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

### Added:

When TextFinder is used for your situation, it becomes as follows. I think that the following script might be a bit simpler.

```
function addCheckbox() {
  var ws =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = ws.getSheetByName('sheet1');

  var ranges = ss.getDataRange()
    .createTextFinder("TRUE")
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findAll()
    .map(r => r.getA1Notation());
  ss.getRangeList(ranges).insertCheckboxes();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: Works Perfect
Thanks you so much Tanaike your the greatest you've help me many time thanks again

Comment: @Yvan L Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I added one more sample script. That uses TextFinder. I think that the following script might be a bit simpler.

Comment: I've switch to use your last code and it work very well also seem faster thanks so much